# Consulta con select y fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos tengo un select dinámico que contiene el nombre de las oficinas de cada empresa y lo que requiero es que primero se seleccione una oficina, luego un rango de fecha y por ultimo exporte un Excel. Tengo los dos últimos puntos pero no me esta cogiendo el valor del select a la hora de filtrar los datos, me exporta todos los datos y necesito que únicamente se exporte la información de la oficina que ha seleccionado , este es el código que utilizo para dicha acción.

Con este código indico cuales son las oficinas que tiene la empresa y también realiza la búsqueda por fechas , Conseguí filtrar las ventas por oficinas, ahora necesito que me descargue un reporte con las ventas de todas las oficinas pertenecientes a la empresa , en este select cargo las oficinas y filtro por oficina y un rango de fecha establecido.

```
<form form method='post' action="reporte.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="empresa" value="<?php echo $proveedor; ?>">
                       <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                               <label>Oficinas</label>
                <select id="ofician" 
                name="oficina" class="form-control ">
                <option>Seleccione una oficina</option>
                <?php
                  $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM oficina where estatus = 1 and proveedor_id=".$_GET['id']." order by nombreOficina");

                  if($sql->execute()){
                    $g_result = $sql->get_result();
                  }
                  while($row = $g_result->fetch_array()){
                ?>
                  <option value = "<?php echo $row['nombreOficina']?>"><?php echo ($row['nombreOficina'])?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                 // $conn->close(); 
                ?>
              </select>
                
                           </div>
                       </div>

                    <div class="row mt-3">
                           <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <label for="fecha_inicio">Fecha Inicio:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from_date" id='from_date' required>
                     </div>
                       <div class="col-lg-6">
                              <label for="fecha_final">Fecha Final:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control"  name="to_date" id='to_date' required>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3 
                        float-right text-uppercase text-white ml-3 font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 13px; letter-spacing: 2px; background-color: #096AA2; border-color: #096AA2;" id="register"
                value= "Exportar" name="generar_reporte">
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    </form>
```

Con esta otra parte genero lo que es el reporte en Excel

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

$from_date = $_POST['from_date'];
$to_date = $_POST['to_date'];
$empresa=$_POST['empresa'];
$oficina=$_POST['oficina'];

if (isset($_POST['generar_reporte'])) {
    
    
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=latin1');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Ventas.csv"');
    
    $salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($salida, array('No.','Fecha Actual', 'Documento', 
    'Primer Apellido', 'Segundo Apellido','Nombre','Genero',
    'Fecha de nacimiento','Edad','Celular','Correo','planCobertura',
    'Opcion','Inicio de Vigencia','Fin de Vigencia','Meses','Prima Total',
    'Asesor','Oficina','Empresa'), ";");

$sql="SELECT * FROM cliente  where (fecha_actual BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') and (empresa='$empresa') and (oficina='$oficina')";
//echo $sql;

$reporteCsv=$conn->query($sql);
    while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
        fputcsv($salida, array ($filaR['idcliente'], 
                                $filaR['fecha_actual'],
                                $filaR['documento'],
                                $filaR['primer_apellido'],
                                $filaR['segundo_apellido'],
                                $filaR['nombre'],
                                $filaR['genero'],
                                $filaR['fecha_naci'],
                                $filaR['edad'],
                                $filaR['celular'],
                                $filaR['correo'],
                                $filaR['planCobertura'],
                                $filaR['opcion'],
                                $filaR['inicio_vigencia'],
                                $filaR['fin_vigencia'],
                                $filaR['meses'],
                                $filaR['prima_total'],
                            utf8_decode($filaR['asesor']),
                            utf8_decode($filaR['oficina']),
                            utf8_decode($filaR['empresa'])), ";");
                        
                            }
                        
?>
```

Comment: te recomiendo ordenar el codigo. asi hasta da peraza leerlo

Comment: veo un "error" en el atributo name en <select id="oficina" class="form-control" name="ofcina"> falta una i

Comment: @eniel.rod si me sirvio pero ahora no me sale nada en la información

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta que no funciona? ¿Qué depuraciones has hecho y con qué resultados? Pulsa en [edit] y aclara mejor la pregunta, ni siquiera indicas dónde es el error exactamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si lo indico , el select dinámico  que contiene las oficinas de la empresa por el cual debo filtrar , ejemplo: en select selecciono Oficina 1 -> luego  seleccione de que fecha a que fecha quiero mi reporte , el me genera el Excel pero sin información cuando la busco sin seleccionar alguna oficina del select me trae la información pero la idea es filtrar por oficina para ello es el select

Comment: No he leído que indiques con claridad cuál es el SELECT que no funciona. De todos modos, pregunto de nuevo: **¿qué has depurado y con qué resultados?** Por ejemplo, haz un `echo` de la instrucción SQL que no funciona, revisa si no tiene errores y pruébala directamente en el SGBD y verifica si devuelve datos. Ese sería uno de los primeros pasos para depurar el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano si en eso si tienes razón, lo que no me captura es el nombre de la oficina , editare la pregunta

Comment: Si tú dices con claridad que el SELECT que no funciona es el del último bloque de código uno va y revisa ese contexto directamente... Por ejemplo, **¿el problema es con la variable `$empresa`?** Tú estás buscando ese dato en `$_POST['empresa']`  pero en el formulario ningún elemento tiene el `name="empresa"`  ... ¿qué se supone que buscas entonces en `$_POST['empresa']`? Lo tuyo es un problema básico de depuración, revisando la consulta como ya dije y los datos posteados con `var_dump($_POST);`  tendrías suficientes elementos de análisis para encontrar el problema.

Comment: no veo que utilices $_POST['ofcina'] (recuerda que falta la i) en la consulta a la BD, ¿de qué forma haces el filtrado por oficina?

Comment: @eniel.rod eso es lo que no logro hacer.

Comment: @eniel.rod ese es el valor que necesito capturar para pasarlo al otro lado y luego de seleccionar la oficina debo seleccionar un rango de fecha pero eso ya esta falta capturar el valor del select de oficina.

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener la oficina

```
$oficina = $_POST['ofcina']; // recuerda que falta la i en el código HTML
```

luego en el SELECT añadir una condición

```
$sql = "... WHERE (cliente.fecha_actual BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') and (cliente.oficina = '$oficina') and (cliente.empresa = '$empresa')";
```

Básicamente esa es la forma, quizás falte algún detalle porque no sé bien como son las relaciones entre las tablas.

Importante, si los parámetros por los que vas a filtrar son opcionales (ejemplo la oficina), entonces deberías tenerlo presente para construir la consulta SQL, pues esto te puede causar resultados no deseados o errores.
Pudieras hacer algo así:

En el formulario le aconsejo que adicione el atributo `value` a la opción "placeholder":

```
<!-- cuidado con los errores en nombres, ej. ofcina, ofician --> 
<select id="ofician" name="oficina" class="form-control ">
    <option value="">Seleccione una oficina</option>
    <!-- resto del código --> 
</select>
```

Luego en el script que gestiona la subida del formulario construya la consulta sql de forma dinámica

```
<?php 

$oficina = $_POST["oficina"];

$sql = "... WHERE (cliente.fecha_actual BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') and (cliente.empresa = '$empresa')";

// Si no adicionas value="" a la primera opción, entonces:
// if($oficina !== 'Seleccione una oficina')
// Ten en cuenta que esto puede traer problemas si el sitio maneja más de un idioma

if($oficina !== "")
{
    // lógica para filtrar por oficina, ej:
    $sql .= " and (cliente.oficina = '$oficina')";
}
```

Además, analiza bien la lógica del WHERE, porque entre oficina y empresa hay una relación (la oficina pertenece a una empresa), creo que al filtrar por oficina no necesitas hacerlo por empresa.

Comment: Sigue sin salirme información en el Excel :(

Comment: @Codej ¿puedes hacer un volcado de la variable sql (var_dump($sql);) para ver cómo queda la consulta que está fallando? También puedes hacer lo mismo para $_POST y actualizar la pregunta con los resultados

Comment: @Codej además, sería bueno conocer el esquema de la BD

Comment: Ya resolví el erro era la consulta del select SELECT * FROM oficina where estatus = 1 and proveedor_id=".$_GET['id']." order by nombreOficina , ahora debo tener una opción de descargar todas las ventas de la empresa en generar sin necesidad de seleccionar oficina  para que asi se desplieguen todas las ventas en general

Comment: @Codej actualicé la respuesta. Lo que debe hacer es construir la consulta de forma dinámica, comprobando los filtros que el usuario utilizó